# Background image of TD not showing in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, email

I've put togethor a simple html email where X 'td' has background images, coded as below...

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="47" height="661" style="background-image:url(http://mysite.com/_includes/emails/invoice/images/l.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y;">
    &nbsp
</td>
```

My problem is that in Outlook the style isnt applied, from what I've found there's nothing wrong with my code, has anybody any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not supported.

For a handy reference, see: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Outlook actually uses the craptacular MS Word rendering engine for HTML. The bane of every email campaign designer.

Comment: But interestingly shows some background-image's but does not show others.The view exactly match with MS-Word's view. Right.